# Rails need to migrate everytime restart server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

When deploying my app to `heroku`, i get some error about migration.

So that I combine all migration, just hold create table file contain all finally property, delete edit table.

Now, everytime restart server(localhost), i have to `db:migrate` again to everything work.

When i just use `db:migrate`, the error said: `table 'product' already existed'`

So i have to `db:drop` first, then `db:migrate` to make my app work
It took me a lot of time.
How can I resolve that issue?
Here is my migrate status:

`up     20190306060445  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20190306060545  Create product
   up     20190307035103  Create active storage tablesactive storage
   up     20190308045037  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190308071304  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20190308072304  Devise create users
   up     20190308074025  Devise create admins
  down    20190308082018  Create categories
   up     20190308083018  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190311041416  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190313084429  Create payment
   up     20190314024236  Create cart
   up     20190314024911  Create cart product
   up     20190314035334  Create messages
   up     20190314145333  Create payment item
   up     20190314151340  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190315020606  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190318073652  Create voucher
   up     20190319035819  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190319134032  Contacts
   up     20190320034249  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190320062223  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190325132236  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190325155829  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190329095529  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190329110656  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190330145000  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190331162926  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190408155326  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190419055934  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190419060341  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190502105847  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190502110019  Add stock
   up     20190506114910  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190506115146  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190506115302  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190513042021  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190513050115  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190514025220  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190514031046  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190516010239  Create comment
   up     20190516020021  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190517132706  Create notification
   up     20190524152143  Create brands
   up     20190527040142  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190528113143  Add columns devise
   up     20190528113658  Add columns devise 1
   up     20190531125307  Create news
   up     20190531144908  Create ckeditor assets
   up     20190601100118  Create news products
   up     20190602144319  Create type of news
   up     20190602155208  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190603062824  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190606172629  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190607074100  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190607122350  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190607140214  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190608082804  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190609051100  Add omniauth to users
   up     20190611115405  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190612071933  Create table carousels
   up     20190612100433  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190613082404  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190614131413  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190615161828  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190617154212  Create district
   up     20190617154602  Create province
   up     20190619140034  Create ward
   up     20190620134528  ********** NO FILE **********
  down    20190620140214  Convert tables to utf8 v1
   up     20190622123753  ********** NO FILE **********`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In changing all your migrations you've created "new" migrations. `rails db:migrate` is trying to apply these "new" migrations to an already existing database. (The list of applied migrations is held in the `schema_migrations` table). We can see all the `down` migrations are the ones which have not been applied. Including `down    20190306060545  Create product`.

Since this is a running production database, presumably the `product` table already exists. When Rails runs migration `20190306060545  Create product` which presumably tries to `create_table :product` it will fail because `product` already exists.

One way to avoid this is to first check if the table exists in your "create table" migrations. If it does, do nothing.

```
if table_exists?(:product)
  return
end
```

To reproduce this in development...

- Check out the original migrations.
- Create a fresh schema from that: `rails db:migrate:reset`
- Check out your new combined migrations.
- Try to migrate: `rails db:migrate`

Comment: I'm RoR newbie. As i know,  rails need to run `rails db:migrate` when changing migration. But i dont do anything, why everytime  restart the server, it ask me to db:migrate again and again. And why not only product, i have combined another table too (vouchers,payments,carts,...), but only product show `down`

Comment: I just realized, when run `rails db:migrate:reset`, `schema_migrations` table just show `up` and `migrations` are existing in `db/migrate`.

Only when I import dump db file to database, it's show all as I  posted above

Comment: @Geogre [Rails needs to migrate any time it sees migrations which have not been applied (aka pending)](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#method-c-check_pending-21). Since you rewrote some migrations Rails thinks they have not been applied and wants to apply them. `rails db:migrate:reset` "works" because it completely blows away your database and reruns *all* the migrations on a fresh, empty database. You obviously don't want to do that to your production database. The point of migrations is to change your database without losing data.

Comment: Thank you very much, you help me know more about rails ^^
I follow your tutorial, create fresh schema_migrations, delete all `down` migration in `schema_migration` in mysqldump file, then use `table_exist` to check in migration file, everything worked fine.